# What is the right way of defining a multiple arity function in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to implement a simple range function in OCaml and I was wondering how can i do that for different arity calls.

```
let range_aux ~start  ~stop  ~step  =
  let rec aux start stop step acc =
    match (start, stop, step, acc) with
    | (start,stop,step,acc) when start = stop -> List.rev acc
    | (start,stop,step,acc) -> aux (start + step) stop step (start :: acc) in
  aux start stop step []

let range ~start ~stop  ~step  = range_aux ~start ~stop ~step
let range ~stop  ~step  = range_aux ~start:0 ~stop ~step
let range ~stop  = range_aux ~start:0 ~stop ~step:1
```

This obviously does not work the last definition wins. Is there a way to define multiple arity functions?

Comment: Don't do that. Use optional arguments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overloading of function does not exist in OCaml in general. For your specific use case, it is possible to use optional arguments:

```
let range ?(start=0) ?(step=1) stop = range_aux ~start ~step ~stop
let a = range 2
let b = range ~start:1 2
let c = range ~start:1 ~step:2 5
```

where `?(start=0)` means that the named argument `start` is optional and its default value is `0`.

Note that I made `stop` a positional argument since the compiler needs a least one positional argument to know when to consume optional arguments.
Another possibility would have been to add an unit argument as a last argument:

```
let range ?(start=0) ?(step=1) ~stop () = range_aux ~start ~step ~stop
let a = range ~stop:2 ()
```

p.s. your `range_aux` will descend into an infinite recursion when `start > stop` or `(stop - start) mod step ≠ 0`.